# sql group by column name

Tags: sql, group-by

I though that GROUP BY must follow by column, but on internet found such example, and don't how and why it works? I am using ORACLE

Working:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(SALARY/5000 , 0), COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY TRUNC(SALARY/5000 , 0);
```

Not working:

```sql
SELECT SALARY, COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY TRUNC(SALARY/5000 , 0);
```

Comment: Read the error meassege it says the group by is not in the select

Comment: ok, but why group by can have not a column name, but division?

Comment: `SALARY/5000` is invalid SQL usually, at least MySQL. You should instead do `SALARY DIV 5000`

Comment: @Stranger: This is not true. There probably isn't any RDBMS where `SALARY/5000` is an invalid operation, provided `SALARY` is some numeric column. As long as the data type allows a decimal point, all DBMS will apply proper division (7500,00 / 5000 = 1.5). If the data type is an integer, then some DBMS (among them SQL Server and PostgreSQL) apply integer division instead (7500 / 5000 = 1). (Which is why in these DBMS it is dangerous to correct a wrong numeric data type sometimes, as this can change the results of long-established queries.)

Comment: Please always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. And when a query results in an error, don't merely say it doesn't work, but show us the error message.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner My bad, I crosschecked and you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Who told you that you can group by columns only? This is just not true.

You group by expressions. These *can* be columns (e.g `salary`) or any other operations on the selected row like `salary * tax`, `salary * 100`, etc.

`GROUP BY x, y` means you want to aggregate your data to get one result row per x/y pair.

If you group by `TRUNC(SALARY/5000 , 0)` you get one result row per expression result. The salaries 5100, 5200, and 9000 will be in one group, because their result is 1, the salaries 11000 and 13000 will be in another.

`COUNT(*)` gives you the number of salaries in that group, but you cannot select `SALARY`, because there is not one salary in the group  you could show, there can be many. If you want to show a salary, decide which one. The minimum `MIN(salary`)? The maximum `MAX(salary`)? The average `AVG(salary`)?